# Error on dropdown with GridView when binding a SelectedValue from the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with multiple columns, the first column has a dropdown that allows the user to select a semester. When they select the semester it should save that selected value to the dropdown. There is a table that loads the dropdown, and then a table that loads the columns. My goal is to allow them to select a value from the dropdown, fill in the other columns, and save the results, so once they come back to the page selected value of the dropdown is shown along with the other data. There essenentially two tables, one for the dropdown for values to select, and another table that houses the actual value selected. When I enter in "Spring" into the main database table that houses the actual value, I get the below error. Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddSemester" runat="server" DataSourceID="SemesterSrc" DataTextField="Semester" DataValueField="SemesterId" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Semester") %>'>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SemesterSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mainConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Semester]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Error:

> $exception    {"'ddSemester' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because
>   it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name:
>   value"}   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

The value I have in the database is Spring, so Spring should show in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue should be a single value in your database, such as "Spring" or "Summer". It should not be set to an entire column of data from your database. Right now, it's trying to bind to a whole column. This is only valid if your select statement returns one row, but I'm not even sure then if that's correct. Do you need selected value to be set on load? Normally, if you have multiple data controls where one control filters a second control, you need two data sources, where one has a filter set:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddSemester" runat="server" DataSourceID="SemesterSrc" DataTextField="Semester" DataValueField="SemesterId">    
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SemesterSrc" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mainConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Semester,SemesterId FROM [Semester]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SemesterSrcFiltered" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mainConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Semester]" FilterExpression="Semester='{0}'">
    <FilterParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="Semester" ControlId="ddSemester" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The DDL will set a value that is used by the FilterParameters section of the SemesterSrcFiltered data source to filter out the data by just that value. You can then use that data source in other controls (like a grid view) to display more information. You should not set both controls to one data source and try to manipulate that data source on the fly with filtering without it unwantedly affecting your DDL too.

Comment: Interesting, I tried adding the filter but I get "Could not find control 'ddSemester' in ControlParameter 'Semester', am I missing something? The dropdown is using the ID of `ddSemester`

Comment: And yes I need the selected value on load. They should be able to select an option, save it, and on reload, the dropdown is defaulted to that selected value.

Comment: The ControlId attribute should match the ID of your Drop Down List. You can see an example of the whole technique here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterparameters?view=netframework-4.8

Also you need to remove the selectedValue bind for sure. Your DDL will retain state automatically. You do not need the SelectedValue bind to it. It's causing an error, as you say, and having it malformed may be causing the DDL to not be a valid choice for the filter. Try it without it.